# -Yarn run build- Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: php, windows, symfony, yarnpkg, symfony6

i'm working on a Symfony 6 Webapp when i ran these commands and everything went well:

```
yarn install
yarn add jquery
yarn add sass-loader  sass --dev
yarn add postcss-loader  autoprefixer --dev
npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
yarn add file-loader@^6.0.0 --dev
yarn add bootstrap
```

---- BUT ----
When i finished everything and wanted to build my project with **Yarn run build** i got a bunch of **errors** :

```
$ yarn run build
yarn run v1.22.19
$ encore production --progress
Running webpack ...

  **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\BADRS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp-14652-VUTb26nHZOob'**

  - node:fs:585 Object.openSync
    node:fs:585:3

  - tmp.js:171 Object.fileSync
    [Exams_Management]/[tmp]/lib/tmp.js:171:15

  - config-generator.js:195 ConfigGenerator.buildEntryConfig
    [Exams_Management]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/config-generator.js:195:39

  - config-generator.js:85 ConfigGenerator.getWebpackConfig
    [Exams_Management]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/config-generator.js:85:25

  - config-generator.js:640 module.exports
    [Exams_Management]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/config-generator.js:640:22

  - index.js:1646 Encore.getWebpackConfig
    [Exams_Management]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/index.js:1646:16

  - EncoreProxy.js:51 Proxy.minDistance
    [Exams_Management]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/lib/EncoreProxy.js:51:53

  - webpack.config.js:91 Object.<anonymous>
    C:/xampp/htdocs/symfony6/Exams_Management/webpack.config.js:91:25

  - loader:1103 Module._compile
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14

  - loader:1155 Object.Module._extensions..js
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10


error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

**PS: Windows 10 pro
**

I visited the given link, nothing works. Could someone please help me fixing this. Thank you so much ^^